# How can I make platform specific RelativeLayout.XConstraint in XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to take `RelativeLayout.XConstraint` with some platform specific value. And also i want to do this in xaml with OnPlatform keyword. 
I tried this one without luck,

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout.XConstraint>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Constraint" Android="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Constant=6" iOS="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Constant=3}" />
     </RelativeLayout.XConstraint>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And also tried this one https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57281/how-can-i-make-platform-specific-relativelayout-xconstraint-in-xaml but it is showing exception "Constraints as specified contain an unsolvable loop".

Here what would be the `x:TypeArguments` for `RelativeLayout.XConstraint` or any other approach? Looking forward to any hints/suggestion on this.

Answer (score 5):

You are applying the constraint to the `RelativeLayout` itself, but constraint are meant to be applied on items of the layout, like this.

```xml
<RelativeLayout>
  <Label Text="Foo">
    <RelativeLayout.XConstraint>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Constraint" Android="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Constant=6}" iOS="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Constant=3}" />
    </RelativeLayout.XConstraint>
  </Label>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, you're missing a closing curly brace (`}`) on the first `ConstraintExpression` markup.

I tested this, it works just fine with XamlC turned off.
 If you are running XF 2.3.3, you might be hitting https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48242, but a fix exists (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/580) and will be released as part of the coming service release.

Comment: Stephane Delcroix I tried this one, but no luck. Constant value is not reflcted for XConstraint/YConstraint.[in case of YConstraint label has been move to the top of the screen] I'm using xamarin form version 2.3.2.127. Any more update on this issue?

Comment: test with the latest service release of XF 2.3.3

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix This has become deprecated. How can we do this with the syntax in 3.3?